# Return List of XML elements from controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I know how to return on XML element from my controller.

What if I need to return a List of a specific class? What I can think of is a wrapper object holding a List. Is there another way to do this?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/xml")
public @ResponseBody
Test getTest() {
    return new Test();
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Test {
    private String name = "kalle";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336875/spring-mvc-responsebody-returning-a-map-produces-error-406-not-acceptable - I found that I had to make sure I had all the right jars available as this answer suggests to correctly return XML.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but you can create custom message converter that converts list into xml vice versa and then inject it to the message converters of the application context.