# In Ajax Response getting whole page : Spring MVC, Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, spring-mvc

I am working on a ajax request/response to update a  table,

But when Ajax put a call to controller I am getting whole page in response. But what i want is only precise table data which i need to map with my c:forEach table. Thanks.

**Jsp View:**

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(document).ready(function(){
           function doAjaxPost() {
                // get the form values
    var contextPath ='<jsp:expression>contextPath</jsp:expression>';

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: contextPath+"/noticesAjaxRequest",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(data){
                        // we have the response
                        $('#info').empty().html(data);

                    },

                    });

                }
          setInterval(doAjaxPost,10*1000);
       });

    </script>  

       <div id="info">
        <c:forEach  items="${noticeForm.noticeList}" var="notice">
            <c:out value="${notice.coreValue} "/>
            <c:out value="${notice.description} "/>
            <br/>
        </c:forEach>
   </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class DashboardController {

private NoticeBO noticeBO;

/*@RequestMapping("/dashboardTest")
public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
    List<Employee> employeeList=dashboardDAO.getAllEmployee();
    for(Employee employee:employeeList)
    model.addAttribute("msg", model.get("msg")+"<br/> Spring 3 MVC Hello World"+employee.getCustomerId());

    return "DashboardTest";

}*/

public NoticeBO getNoticeBO() {
    return noticeBO;
}

public void setNoticeBO(NoticeBO noticeBO) {
    this.noticeBO = noticeBO;
}

@RequestMapping("/dashboard")
public String dashboard(ModelMap model) {
    return "Dashboard";
}

@RequestMapping("/notices")
public ModelAndView notices(@ModelAttribute("NoticeForm") NoticeForm noticeForm, ModelMap model) {

    noticeBO.prepareNoticeList(noticeForm,model);

    return new ModelAndView("notices","noticeForm",noticeForm);
}

@RequestMapping("/noticesAjaxRequest")
public ModelAndView noticesAjaxRequest(@ModelAttribute("NoticeForm") NoticeForm noticeForm, ModelMap model) {

    noticeBO.prepareNoticeList(noticeForm,model);

    return new ModelAndView("notices", "noticeForm", noticeForm);
}
}
```

**Update{1}:**

I tried a change in controller and it starts giving me Error: [object XMLHttpRequest]

```
 @RequestMapping("/noticesAjaxRequest")
public @ResponseBody List<Notice> noticesAjaxRequest(@ModelAttribute("NoticeForm") NoticeForm noticeForm, ModelMap model) {

    noticeBO.prepareNoticeList(noticeForm,model);

    return noticeForm.getNoticeList();
}
```

Error Description:

HTTP Status 406-The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

Response Headers

```
Content-Length  1067
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Thu, 11 Jul 2013 12:48:19 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Request Headers

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cookie  JSESSIONID=D54D66F6B7FE05C2B6FB684BF19387F1
Host    localhost:8080
Referer http://localhost:8080/vServFinance/notices
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you friends for your help. Best and Easy one is to create the **separate jsp view** and include that while returning/responding from controller.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
           function doAjaxPost() {
                // get the form values
               var contextPath ='<jsp:expression>contextPath</jsp:expression>';

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: contextPath+"/noticesAjaxRequest",
                    success: function(data){
                        // we have the response

                         $('#info').html(data); 
                        /* $('#info').refresh(); */
                    },

                     error: function(e){
                        alert('Error: ' + e);
                    } 
                    });
                }
          setInterval(doAjaxPost,10*1000);
       });
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/noticesAjaxRequest")
public  ModelAndView noticesAjaxRequest(@ModelAttribute("NoticeForm") NoticeForm noticeForm, ModelMap model) {

    noticeBO.prepareNoticeList(noticeForm,model);

    return new ModelAndView("/noticesList","noticeForm",noticeForm);
}
```

Comment: That is the fastest way! Thanks! If you are used to return String, here is a sample response:

            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("PATH/TO/JSP");
            mav.getModelMap().addAllAttributes(model.asMap());
            return mav;

Comment: Thanks. have no time to test this.

Comment: what do you mean by a separate jsp view? You mean the jsp and the js for ajax call should not be in the same page?

Comment: @Atais model.asMap is not a method!

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP 406 is probably caused by not having the `jackson-core-asl` and `jackson-mapper-asl` jars on the classpath. See [here](http://yabor.adrianmejia.com/posts/spring-mvc-3-ajax-getjson-and-solving-406-not-accepted) and the Stack Overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336875/spring-mvc-responsebody-returning-a-map-produces-error-406-not-acceptable).

To summarise, if you're using Maven, you would add the following two dependencies to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

If not using Maven, just ensure that the two jars above are present on the classpath.

Comment: I am not sure how i am going to manipulate the json object into list later, Any idea.

Answer (score 1):

On your code you are returning a ModelAndView, this will return a view. If you want to return  a JSON Data you need to add the @ResponseBody to your return type. Like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/porUF", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Municipio> municipios(
            @RequestParam(value = "uf", required = true) String uf) {

        if ( uf.length() != 2) {
            return null;    
        }

        return municipioBO.findByUf(uf);
    }
```

This will transform the LIST into a JSON object. The HTTP response will be like:

```
[{"codigo":9701,"uf":{"uf":"DF","nome":"DISTRITO FEDERAL"},"nome":"BRASILIA"}]
```

To do that, you'll need some library to do this MAGIC of transforming the object into a JSON object. I'm using Jackson. Add it to your POM:

```
<!-- Data Mapper package is a high-performance data binding package built 
        on Jackson JSON processor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You mean if i add the jar in my classpath, it will automatically transform the object into json object ?

Comment: Yep, the JAR plus the annotation @ResponseBody do the magic ;)